# Using Adafruit RFM96W with Raspberry Pi for a end node of The Things Network

Tags: python, windows-iot, adafruit

I am trying to create a Raspberry Pi 3 end node with the [Adafruit RFM96W](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3073) module and [raspi-lora](https://pypi.org/project/raspi-lora/) library but it seems that the library has no configurable APPSKEY, NWKSKEY, DEVADDR and etc., so I won't be able to receive downlinks from [The Things Network](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/), which is what I want. Does any of you have ideas on how I can do it? Or do you know other libraries that can be used in my case?
Thanks in advance !:)

Comment: Are you trying to build a gateway or just get data to the 'Things Network'?   If its the gateway then your code handles the communication and sets the needed values for the API If its the latter then you should be looking at https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/applications/options.html

Comment: I am trying to make an end node that just receives data from the adafruit rfm96w module and uses it. The idea is that I will send data to the LoRa module on the PI as downlink from The Things Network and the PI will use it to trigger something. 0A will trigger a relay for example.